# Makefiles: how to detach folder name from long path

Tags: sed, makefile

I need to detach a folder name from a long path, e.g.: `../../folder1/folder2 -> folder2`. If it was a file name - the nodir function could be used. But nodir doesn't work with directories.

I have tried to use the following approach:

```
LIBNAMES := echo $(LIBS) | sed  -e 's/\\S*\///g'
```

where LIBS is a list of long path folders. After implementing it my first impression was that it works (the correct LIBNAMES result was printed). But the following LIBNAMES usage in my makefile ended with strange errors: it seems the sed command itself somehow was added to the result. So, where is my mistake?

Comment: @MadScientist Thanks for the correction to my opinion concerning nodir function: yes, it works!... My mistake.

Comment: In any case I want to understand what is incorrect in echo + sed approach. Can be sed used in makefiles in such manner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you say that `notdir` doesn't work with directories?  It works with any path.

```
all: ; echo $(notdir $(CURDIR))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ CURDIR="../../folder1/folder2"

$ echo ${CURDIR##*/}
folder2
```

#### Here is the explanation of usage `##` in bash (copy from bash manual)

```
${parameter#word}
${parameter##word}
The word is expanded to produce a pattern just as in filename expansion (see Filename Expansion). If the pattern matches the beginning of the expanded value of parameter, then the result of the expansion is the expanded value of parameter with the shortest matching pattern (the ‘#’ case) or the longest matching pattern (the ‘##’ case) deleted. If parameter is ‘@’ or ‘*’, the pattern removal operation is applied to each positional parameter in turn, and the expansion is the resultant list. If parameter is an array variable subscripted with ‘@’ or ‘*’, the pattern removal operation is applied to each member of the array in turn, and the expansion is the resultant list.

${parameter%word}
${parameter%%word}
The word is expanded to produce a pattern just as in filename expansion. If the pattern matches a trailing portion of the expanded value of parameter, then the result of the expansion is the value of parameter with the shortest matching pattern (the ‘%’ case) or the longest matching pattern (the ‘%%’ case) deleted. If parameter is ‘@’ or ‘*’, the pattern removal operation is applied to each positional parameter in turn, and the expansion is the resultant list. If parameter is an array variable subscripted with ‘@’ or ‘*’, the pattern removal operation is applied to each member of the array in turn, and the expansion is the resultant list.
```